# HTTP input filter like mod_security for WebSphere?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, xss, sql-injection, mod-security

Does WebSphere offer an HTTP input filter / firewall like mod_security?

I know that it's possible to have Apache be the HTTP server front-end to WebSphere, but that type of configuration is beyond my influence.  We're stuck using just what WebSphere itself can do.

EDIT - To clarify, I am not looking for authentication, authorization, or non-repudiation aspects of security here.  I want a rule-based HTTP firewall like mod_security that works on WebSphere.

Also, I know that in version 1.x, there was a partial implementation of mod_security in Java.  We currently have a custom, in-house solution that is a work-alike, but less arbitrarily configurable.  Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, you asked a pretty hard question!

Comment: Yeah.  There is also the theory that you should not care about filtering; just escape everything on its way in.  There are lots of scenarios where filtering is still necessary, though.

Answer (score 1):

J2EE has a [standard](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Security.html) way of [securing](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Security4.html#67530) it's apps.  I recommend using this.  If what you are trying to do is oddball, you could look at [Custom User Registries (IBM specific)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v5r1//index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rsec_customauth.html), or implement a custom system all together with [Servlet Filters](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pj2ee10.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  We have currently implemented filtering using Servlet Filters.  However, we are not in the HTTP input filtering business, so I'd rather use a prepackaged solution like mod_security.

Answer (score 0):

There are many attacks that target the web server in front of your application server, so you should get control of the configuration of that web server too.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at webcastellum http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcastellum/
It is an Java Opensource WAF.
Sadly the Wesbsite of the maintainers is in German only but they seem to have some english documentation.

They say in their Documentation WebCastellum is compatibel to all common J2EE-Servers:
WebCastellum ist kompatibel zu allen gängigen JavaEE-Servern
Bei der Implementierung von WebCastellum wurde auf Kompatibilität zu allen
gängigen JavaEE-Servern, wie Tomcat, BEA Weblogic, JBoss oder WebSphere
Wert gelegt.